# Не выводит информацию с бд

Tags: php, mysql

На странице type-vehicule.php выводиться информация о типах эвакуаторов
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пытался добавить один столбец в бд, всё работает, даже при добавление информации на странице type-vehicule.php, всё заноситься в бд, но вот вывести эту информацию не могу выдаёт ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Notice: Undefined index: priс in /var/www/u0816629/data/www/eva.cordream.com/on_demand_taxi/type-vehicule.php on line 288

Из скриншота выше видно что не выводиться столбец с названием "Цена погрузки"

Вот строка 288 из ошибки которая и отвечает за вывод нужной информации

```
<td>'.$tab_type_vehicule[$i]['pric'].'</td>
```

Вот полный код скрипта

```
<?php
                                                for($i=0; $i<count($tab_type_vehicule); $i++){
                                                    echo'
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td>'.($i+1).'</td>
                                                            <td>'.$tab_type_vehicule[$i]['libelle'].'</td>
                                                            <td>'.$tab_type_vehicule[$i]['prix'].'</td>
                                                            <td>'.$tab_type_vehicule[$i]['pric'].'</td>
                                                            <td width="10%"><img width="100%" src="assets/images/type_vehicle/'.$tab_type_vehicule[$i]['image'].'" alt=""></td>
                                                            <td>'.$tab_type_vehicule[$i]['creer'].'</td>
                                                            <td>'.$tab_type_vehicule[$i]['modifier'].'</td>
                                                            
                                                        </tr>
                                                    ';
                                                }
                                            ?>
```

query/action.php

```
/* End catégorie utilisateur */

/* Start type véhicule */
if((isset($_POST['libelle_type_vehicule']) && !empty($_POST['libelle_type_vehicule']))
&& (isset($_POST['price_vehicule']) && !empty($_POST['price_vehicule']))
&& (isset($_POST['pric_vehicule']) && !empty($_POST['pric_vehicule']))
&& (isset($_FILES['image_vehicule']) && !empty($_FILES['image_vehicule']))){

    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["image_vehicule"]["name"]);
    $newfile = 'image_vehicle_type'.'_'.microtime(true).'_'.rand(0,round(microtime(true)));
    $extension = '.'.end($temp);
    $newfilename = $newfile.''.$extension;
    
    $target_dir = '../assets/images/type_vehicle/';
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($newfilename);
    $upload_ok = 1;
    $image_file_type = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    
    if($image_file_type == 'jpg' || $image_file_type == 'png' || $image_file_type == 'jpeg' || $image_file_type == 'gif'){
        $target_dir = "../assets/images/type_vehicle/";
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($newfilename);
    }

    // Check file size
    if ($_FILES["image_vehicule"]["size"] > 10000000) { //10Mo
        //echo "File too big.";
        $upload_ok = 0;
    }
    // Limit allowed file formats
    if($image_file_type != "jpg" && $image_file_type != "png" && $image_file_type != "jpeg" && $image_file_type != "JPG" && $image_file_type != "PNG" && $image_file_type != "JPEG") {
        //echo "Only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
        $upload_ok = 0;
    }
    // Check if $upload_ok is set to 0 by an error
    if ($upload_ok == 0) {
        echo "Your file was not uploaded.";
        $_SESSION['status'] = 3;
        header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    // If all the checks are passed, file is uploaded
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image_vehicule"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            //echo "The file ". basename($newfilename). " was uploaded.";
            
            $res = setTypeVehicule($_POST['libelle_type_vehicule'],$_POST['price_vehicule'],$_POST['pric_vehicule'],$newfilename);
            if($res == 1){
                $_SESSION['status'] = 1;
                header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
            }else{
                $_SESSION['status'] = 2;
                header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
            }
        } else {
            //echo "A error has occured uploading.";
            $_SESSION['status'] = 2;
            header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
        }
    }
}

if((isset($_POST['id_type_vehicule_mod']) && !empty($_POST['id_type_vehicule_mod'])) 
&& (isset($_POST['libelle_type_vehicule_mod']) && !empty($_POST['libelle_type_vehicule_mod']))
&& (isset($_POST['price_vehicule_mod']) && !empty($_POST['price_vehicule_mod']))
&& (isset($_POST['pric_vehicule_mod']) && !empty($_POST['pric_vehicule_mod']))
&& (isset($_FILES['image_vehicule_mod']) && !empty($_FILES['image_vehicule_mod']))){
    
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["image_vehicule_mod"]["name"]);
    $newfile = 'image_vehicle_type'.'_'.microtime(true).'_'.rand(0,round(microtime(true)));
    $extension = '.'.end($temp);
    $newfilename = $newfile.''.$extension;
    
    $target_dir = '../assets/images/type_vehicle/';
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($newfilename);
    $upload_ok = 1;
    $image_file_type = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    
    if($image_file_type == 'jpg' || $image_file_type == 'png' || $image_file_type == 'jpeg' || $image_file_type == 'gif'){
        $target_dir = "../assets/images/type_vehicle/";
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($newfilename);
    }

    // Check file size
    if ($_FILES["image_vehicule_mod"]["size"] > 10000000) { //10Mo
        //echo "File too big.";
        $upload_ok = 0;
    }
    // Limit allowed file formats
    if($image_file_type != "jpg" && $image_file_type != "png" && $image_file_type != "jpeg" && $image_file_type != "JPG" && $image_file_type != "PNG" && $image_file_type != "JPEG") {
        //echo "Only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
        $upload_ok = 0;
    }
    // Check if $upload_ok is set to 0 by an error
    if ($upload_ok == 0) {
        echo "Your file was not uploaded.";
        $_SESSION['status'] = 3;
        header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    // If all the checks are passed, file is uploaded
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image_vehicule_mod"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            //echo "The file ". basename($newfilename). " was uploaded.";
            
            $res = setTypeVehiculeMod($_POST['id_type_vehicule_mod'],$_POST['libelle_type_vehicule_mod'],$_POST['price_vehicule_mod'],$_POST['pric_vehicule_mod'],$newfilename);
            // if($res == 1)
                $_SESSION['status'] = 1;
                header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
        } else {
            //echo "A error has occured uploading.";
            $_SESSION['status'] = 2;
            header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
        }
    }
}

if((isset($_GET['id_type_vehicule']))){
    delTypeVehicule($_GET['id_type_vehicule']);
    $_SESSION['status'] = 1;
    header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
}
/* End type véhicule */
```

quuery/fonction.php

```
/* Start Type véhicule */
function setTypeVehicule($libelle,$prix,$pric,$image){
    include("connexion.php");
    $con->set_charset("utf8");
    $res = '0';
    $libelle = str_replace("'","\'",$libelle);
    $prix = str_replace("'","\'",$prix);
    $pric = str_replace("'","\'",$pric);
    $date_heure = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $sql_verif = "SELECT id FROM tj_type_vehicule WHERE libelle='$libelle'";
    $result_verif = mysqli_query($con,$sql_verif);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result_verif) > 0){
        $res = '2';
    }else{
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tj_type_vehicule (libelle, creer, prix, pric, image) VALUES ('$libelle', '$date_heure', '$prix', '$pric', '$image')";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        if($result == 1){
            $res = '1';
        } else {
            $res = '0';
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
    return $res;
}

function setTypeVehiculeMod($id,$libelle,$prix,$pric,$image){
    include("connexion.php");
    $con->set_charset("utf8");
    $res = '0';
    $libelle = str_replace("'","\'",$libelle);
    $prix = str_replace("'","\'",$prix);
    $pric = str_replace("'","\'",$pric);
    $date_heure = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $sql = "UPDATE tj_type_vehicule SET image='$image', libelle='$libelle', prix='$prix', pric='$pric', modifier='$date_heure' WHERE id=$id";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    
    mysqli_close($con);
    return $res;
}


function getTypeVehicule(){
    include("connexion.php");
    $con->set_charset("utf8");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tj_type_vehicule";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $output[] = $row;
    }
    
    mysqli_close($con);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        return $output;
    }else{
        return $output = [];
    }
}

function getTypeVehiculeById($id_type){
    include("connexion.php");
    $con->set_charset("utf8");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tj_type_vehicule WHERE id=$id_type";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $output[] = $row;
    }
    
    mysqli_close($con);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        return $output;
    }else{
        return $output = [];
    }
}

function getIdTypeVehiculeByLibelle($lib_annee){
    include("connexion.php");
    $con->set_charset("utf8");
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM tj_type_vehicule WHERE libelle='$lib_annee'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    // output data of each row
    $id = 0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $id = $row['id'];
    }
    
    mysqli_close($con);
    return $id;
}

function delTypeVehicule($id){
    include("connexion.php");
    $con->set_charset("utf8");
    $sql = "DELETE FROM tj_type_vehicule WHERE id=$id";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    mysqli_close($con);
}

function getLastTypeVehicule(){
    include("connexion.php");
    $con->set_charset("utf8");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tj_type_vehicule ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $output[] = $row;
    }
    
    mysqli_close($con);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        return $output;
    }else{
        return $output = [];
    }
}
/* End Type véhicule */
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

JS Script

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myTable').DataTable();
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('#example').DataTable({
            "columnDefs": [{
                "visible": false,
                "targets": 2
            }],
            "order": [
                [2, 'asc']
            ],
            "displayLength": 25,
            "drawCallback": function(settings) {
                var api = this.api();
                var rows = api.rows({
                    page: 'current'
                }).nodes();
                var last = null;
                api.column(2, {
                    page: 'current'
                }).data().each(function(group, i) {
                    if (last !== group) {
                        $(rows).eq(i).before('<tr class="group"><td colspan="5">' + group + '</td></tr>');
                        last = group;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        // Order by the grouping
        $('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr.group', function() {
            var currentOrder = table.order()[0];
            if (currentOrder[0] === 2 && currentOrder[1] === 'asc') {
                table.order([2, 'desc']).draw();
            } else {
                table.order([2, 'asc']).draw();
            }
        });
    });
});
$('#example24').DataTable();
</script>
<!-- ============================================================== -->
<!-- Style switcher -->
<!-- ============================================================== -->
<script src="assets/plugins/styleswitcher/jQuery.style.switcher.js"></script>
<script>
    function modTypeVehicule(id_type){
        $.ajax({
            url: "query/ajax/getTypeVehiculeById.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {"id_type":id_type},
            success: function (data) {
                $("#id_type_vehicule_mod").empty();
                $("#libelle_type_vehicule_mod").empty();
                $("#price_vehicule_mod").empty();
                $("#pric_vehicule_mod").empty();

                var data_parse = JSON.parse(data);

                $("#id_type_vehicule_mod").val(data_parse[0].id);
                $("#libelle_type_vehicule_mod").val(data_parse[0].libelle);
                $("#price_vehicule_mod").val(data_parse[0].prix);
                $("#pric_vehicule_mod").val(data_parse[0].pric);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Вот что показывает print_r
И я так понимаю что в масиве есть pric

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 7 [libelle] => Эвакуатор [prix] => 35 [pric] => 2500 [image] => image_vehicle_type_1573996336.5819_16352010.png [creer] => 2019-11-17 12:07:09 [modifier] => 2019-11-17 13:12:16 )
```

Comment: Запрос в бд и её структуру можно посмотреть? Проверьте правильность в написании таблицы.

Comment: @Виталий Бриль Добавил запросы в бд

Comment: Что показывает `print_r($tab_type_vehicule)` в масиве есть поле `pric`?

Comment: @Dmitriy Kondratiuk в массиве есть поле `pric`!

Comment: После того как я добавил код `print_r($tab_type_vehicule);` вывелся массив. После удаления кода `print_r($tab_type_vehicule);` В таблице всё вывелось, странно как то!

Comment: @DENGIPAY, скорее всего всё это было из-за опечатки.(?)

Comment: А какая опечатка может быть если кроме того что я показал массив а потом скрыл его?